# Grafana: Template variables are not supported in alert queries

Tags: grafana

I am new to grafana and have just setup my first dashboard with node_eporter_full template downloaded from the official grafana site.

Now I have set up messenger and want to set the first alarm. Unfortunatelly this does not work on any chart. The message I get is "Template variables are not supported in alert queries"

How can I setup an alert. E.g. if CPU is > 90%?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6557 This issue is pending as a feature request from 2016 but the grafana devs have chosen rather to lock the thread than work on this feature

Answer (score 2):

From https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/create-alerts/

`The query used in an alert rule cannot contain any template variables.`

Basically you need to create a query for the thing you're specifically interested in, and then you can create an alert for that.